# Can a prepositional phrase be a subject?

Tags: grammaticality

Is a prepositional phrase acceptable as a subject ?

I got this grammar book yesterday, need not to mention its author
Book title ( Whose grammar book is this anyway? )
On page 25 I found this: (words substituting a noun appears in bold). I'll also indicate what
noun function the noun substitute is serving:

1. Prepositional phrase acting as the subject of the sentence.

> - **Under the table** is the place to look.

I think it is the same with a sentence starts by (here or there) and neither here or there is a subject but the noun which follows.

Comment: 'The place to look is under the table' would be a re-phrasing.

Comment: Yes, any kind of phrase can be used as a subject, given the right predicate and context. That makes it a prepositional phrase acting as a noun, because subjects are considered noun phrases. Ditto clauses, like _That she left early was unfortunate;_ they're often called "noun clauses" because they can be subjects. Phrasal subjects like this are automatically singular, and neuter.

Comment: @JohnLawler I am always surprised that people such as yourself fail to address the kind of thing we recently saw on ze ozzer site that claimed that in "As suggested is your best option", "as suggested" is the subject of the sentence. The poster even asked me if I am a native speaker of English when I balked at that structure.  What say you? I don't, of course, object to: Your best option is as suggested.

Comment: Possibly the OP deserves a 'back'-migration; it is certainly interesting. However, it sounds like _**Yoda-speak**_

Comment: @Lambie - I'm sorry, but I don't know what you're referring to. Grammaticality is a measure of how difficult it is to find a context in which the sentence makes sense. IF you pronounce "As suggested" properly, indicating that it's a quote, and the name of one of the official options to choose among, you have a perfectly grammatical English sentence, of a speaker giving advice to somebody filling out a form. Like I said, in the right context, with the right pronunciation, anything can work. I'm sorry you were subjected to opprobrium, but I feel no responsibility for it.

Comment: @JohnLawler I believe you concluded that here in OP's sentence the Preposition Phrase - "under the table" - is the subject. Yes I too think so. But it is really painful for a learner/student to distinguish it when the same Preposition Phrase in the same position in another sentence is not a subject. For example in this sentence "Under the table is the pen.", here "under the table" is not the subject.

Comment: In this question also the Preposition phrase is not the subject. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/290940/where-is-the-subject-of-this-sentence/290941#290941

Comment: "Under the table" isn't the subject. It is a prepositional phrase that forms the predicate adjective in an inverted sentence in which "the place to look" is the complete subject. It's no different than saying, "Sad is how I feel." "Sad" is not a noun. It is an adjective, the predicate adjective, just like that prepositional phrase is. The subject is "how I feel," just like "the place to look" is. Or, if you prefer, make my example, "Sad is John," also an inverted sentence in which the predicate adjective appears before the verb and the subject appears afterwards.

Comment: @BanjaminHarman "sad is how I feel" and "sad is John" are not similar. "Sad" in the first sentence is a noun, a subject. It is a subject not because it is a noun. In the second sentence it is an adjective. It is a complement in this sentence as well, but it is not the subject. It is a Predicative Complement.

Comment: Yes: it's the subject, as the interrogative tests prove (see my answer).

Comment: A duplicate of [Can you treat a prepositional phrase as the subject?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/428983/can-you-treat-a-prepositional-phrase-as-the-subject) Though the OP's example is not appropriate, tchrist answers the title question.

Comment: @JohnLawler Of course, if you put "as suggested" in quotes, which then makes it refer to an antecedent of some kind or a substitution. I am not blaming you. I am saying that I am surprised by your not stepping in. Now there's a usage not all will get. :)

Comment: @Lambie Life is full of surprises.

Comment: @JohnLawler Look at this link where you wrote a comment saying "No" for this structure. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/428983/can-you-treat-a-prepositional-phrase-as-the-subject You say that sentence has a fronted locative phrase. Which I believe is what I said here for the same structure but without the word fronted. Indeed, many surprises.

Answer (score 4):

> *Under the table is the place to look.*

Yes: the PP "under the table" is the subject here.

This can be demonstrated by the possibility of having an interrogative tag, "isn't it?", where "it"  is anaphoric to "under the table" , showing that the latter is subject.

The basic interrogative test for subjects also proves it's the subject: "Is under the table the place to look?"

Edit, as requested in comments:

There is no subject-dependent inversion here, as there would be in, say, *On* *her desk was a bowl of fruit*, where the PP *on her desk* is not the subject but a preposed locative complement.

Comment: I am adding your comment from the other, now-deleted answer. Maybe you could add it to your answer: *There is no subject-dependent inversion [in "Under the table is the place to look"], as there would be in, for example, "On her desk was a bowl of fruit", where the PP "on her desk" is not the subject but a locative complement.*

Comment: Thank you. @https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/31780/billj Your comment helped me and I searched again ... Acceptable or not acceptable that's the grammar  Thank you again and I am gratified for you. Sorry for my  first comments I excuse

Comment: You are adding a tag. My inversion example does not add anything unnatural. Again, if it isn't an inversion, inversion in English make no sense.

Comment: The tag is useful to demonstrate that the PP "under the table" must be the subject. The pronoun subject of a tag corresponds to the subject of the main clause. In this case the subject of the tag, "it", refers to the PP "under the table", thus proving that the latter is the subject of the main clause. (Note that even if this were a case of inversion (which it isn't), it would not be subject-verb inversion, but subject-dependent inversion.

Comment: Hello @https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/31780/billj  Please here me suppose it ( plural noun ( places) : Under the table is \ are  the places to look.   Subject - Verb -agreement  How it should be ( are or is )  think again

Comment: @AhmadMohammad whether it is singular or plural verb depends on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

For me, that is an inversion, which is great English, by the way.

It is an inversion of the usual order used for effect.
*The place to look is under the table.*

With the bare form of be, it's easy, usually.

For me, the subject is the phrase **The place to look** and **under the table** is just a prepositional phrase, an adjunct of location. And this is basically a locative inversion. "Up the river swam the salmon". instead of: "The salmon swam up the river."

English inverts many things, all the time. It is a major poetic device.

Shakespeare:
*Uneasy lies the head that wears a crown.*
for
The head lies uneasy that wears the crown.

For me, these sentences require being put in a natural order in order to find the subject or predicate.

**If English didn't invert the the verb and subject, there would no such thing as inversion.**

Here is the wikipedia page that can get you started on inversion:

[subject-verb inversion in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English)

Comment: But *Under the bed is dusty* is not an inversion. *Under the bed* functions as a subject and a noun.

Comment: Most native speakers would say "It is dusty under the bed", using a dummy subject.

Comment: @TinfoilHat That is not the same as the one at hand. Yes, it is a type of elision.

Comment: But the question asks: *Is a prepositional phrase acceptable as a subject?* Yes, it is.

Comment: I'm  gonna bail...

Comment: @TinfoilHat I consider certain sentences are truncations or elisions. In the question given, it is an inversion and therefore, in that case, no, it is not the subject. For me, Under the bed is dusty. is an elision of What is dusty is under the bed or It is dusty under the bed.

Comment: *What is dusty is under the bed* means that dusty things are under the bed. The "dummy *it*" in *It is dusty under the bed* represents a syntactic, "placeholder" subject for a postponed semantic subject.

Comment: @Lambie I agree with you I posted it in my group on Facebook saying to my students the same you said ( It is the same way with a sentence starts by ( here, there )  >>Under the table is the place to look. It is inverted ( under the table ) = adverb and the subject = the place. Simply its origin = The place to look is under the table https://www.facebook.com/groups/MohammadTranslatorMosul

Comment: In some English dialects, "Under the bed needs cleaning" would be normal usage. It's not obvious how that is an "inversion." "It needs cleaning under the bed" doesn't make sense because there is nothing for "it" to refer to.

Comment: @alephzero Under the bed needs cleaning [by someone]=Cleaning [by someone] is needed under the bed. It's a version of an inversion.

Comment: On the other hand, "In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit" clearly *is* an inversion of the boringly prosaic sentence "A hobbit lived in a hole in the ground"

Comment: @Lambie You can invent whatever language you like and call it "English" (after all, 300m Americans are a good precedent for doing that) but nobody who says "Under the bed needs cleaning" would ever say something as pretentiously formal as "Cleaning is needed under the bed."

Comment: @alephzero Nope, you added "there".  Hobbits, by the way, live in hobbit-holes, smials or burrows. Just because an inversion is more **prevalent** does not mean it ain't one. I can imagine a housekeeper in a mansion or estate saying to the maids: Cleaning is needed under the beds. And, it's perfectly English, HA HA And just try:  Cleaning is needed under the rubber mats, under the ice machine, under the sink, etc. etc. ad nauseum in administrative lingo. What people **say** and **write** often differs.

Comment: See the answer by @BillJ to understand the difference between *Under the table is the place to look* and  *Under the table is the box*. Only the latter is a subject-verb inversion.

Comment: @TinfoilHat No, they both are. He just claims it; he does not prove it. He claims there is an interrogative test. And I say you can reverse them. Mine adds nothing to the phrases, his involves **adding something**. I know the difference.

Comment: @Lambie interrogative test is very helpful here. You see how in interrogative sentence subject comes after verb. And he very well proved that PP follows the rule. He also demonstrated the "tag test".

Comment: @Man_From_India Try **the** inversion test.

Comment: @Lambie will it give real answer here? See in my comment under the question I have written two sentences consisting of sane PP at the same place but they are not functioning the same way. One is subject and the other is locative complement.

Answer (score 0):

I see it is mentioned in two sites that a preposition phrase can be a noun, **so in case its function = noun it can be either subject or complement, though it seems odd to many learners  >>**
Here are results from two sites **but no any results from books except one book** which I found on Google books
1- from : https://www.grammarly.com/blog/prepositional-phrase/
Prepositional Phrases Acting as Nouns

Less frequently, prepositional phrases can function like nouns in a sentence.

During the national anthem is the worst time to blow your nose.

After the game will be too late for us to go to dinner.
2- From : https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-7/prepositions/lesson-6/prepositional-phrases-as-nouns
In front of the class is a stressful place to be. (subject)
The most stressful place for me is in front of the class. (subject complement)

In these cases, there is usually a noun in front of the prepositional phrase that is implied or understood, but not written.

```
(The spot) in front of the class is a stressful place to be.
The most stressful place for me is (the spot) in front of the class.    But the matter is still confusing with a subject -Verb agreement Suppose the noun which comes after the prepositional phrase = **plural**
```

Under the table are the **places** to look.  Do we use a singular verb in such instance ?   **Lastly I refuse the information under the the links above**

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions at hand.  One is whether any prepositional phrase appears as a subject in any coherent clause.  Another is whether the given example counts as a subjective prepositional phrase, as the textbook suggests it does.

Regarding the latter, context and intent are relevant, but they're not supplied.

We have a copular clause.  English copular clauses allow subject/complement inversion:  Both "the meek are blessed" and "blessèd are the meek" treat "the meek" as the subject.  We can't determine what counts as the subject from the word position alone.

That's how context and intent are relevant.

A subject complement is either another reference to the subject's referent or it is a licensed attribution of the subject.  The typical examples of those are called *predicate nouns* and *predicate adjectives* respectively.

When one constituent is an obvious attribution, the other must be the subject.  There's no grammatical ambiguity in "blessèd are the meek".

When the complement is a substantive reference, there is an ambiguity.

You have options.  You could parse "under the table" as "[the area] under the table", and claim that the subject is elliptical.  You could treat "under the table" as a *substantive prepositional phrase* in parallel with *substantive adjectives,* although that might be a distinction without a difference.  Alternately, you could parse "under the table" as the attribute and the topic, leaving "the place to look" as the referential subject.

> Under the table is fine.

Here, we can't find any substantive reference other than "[the area] under the table".  We don't have the option of regarding "under the table" as an attribution of the adjective "fine".

The textbook's example isn't a good example.  It's ambiguous.  Without some clearly clarifying context, we can't identify which constituent is the subject.  Either could be.

However, we can find sentences that don't have any other candidate for the subject role except for some prepositional phrase (or, at least, an elliptical reference that such a phrase suggests and modifies).

Whether it *is* or merely *indicates* a subject might be a hair-splitting philosophical distinction.  Sometimes a prepositional phrase is the only constituent that even comes close to filling one of those possibilities.

Comment: subjective prepositional phrase sounds like the opposite of an objective prepositional phrase. We would say: prepositional phrase **as subject**.